# Change the transparency of an Android stock icon?

Tags: gimp, icon, transparency, android

I am trying to use an android star icon (.png) and color it in red. Basic, right? Well.

I did the color change after some research (just download Gimp 2) from an iOS icon because it has the ideal size 64*64 but it resulted in small legs drooling from the star lowest spikes once displayed on the Android device.

So now I am fighting to do the same from an Android icon (a little smaller but why not?). So far I have achieved a nice result. BUT it is **pink** not the deep red I wanted and obtained before. So we figured it was due to an existing transparency of the star. We tried to add layer to change it, inverse layering, copy paste it, color the result but nothing, the results are always pink.

To resume : from iOS icon : **color perfect but strange shaping effects** versus from android icon : **shape perfect (even if smaller) but color pinky or transparent**

How can I "remove" the transparency that might be in the initial .png ?

Edit : I just try drawing stars with Inkscape, the result is not okay :D I have the same small "legs"  :(

Edit : Several picture of my different test :

Test 1 : android icon re-colored with still the transparency --> pink color as a result.

[image: android icon re-colored with still the transparency --> pink color as a result.]

Test 2 : I follow your advice and get this :

[image: transparency removed :]

Test 3 : I tried to use anti aliasing filter but there is little difference :

[image: anti aliasing filter]

My work blocks imgur so I cannot see if all uploaded ok.

Answer (score 1):

Create a selection from the original icon and apply it as a mask to a filled layer.

Comment: ok i start searching how to do that, brb. What does "filled" means? White ?

Comment: Good news: Don't even ask me how I get it right but it indeed removed the transparency effect. I suppose it's a mirror trick? Thanks! 

Bad news: The star shape is all irregular probably due to the inverse selection I did? How to soften it up? (i start looking for that online but if u have a second hint, i am all hears :)

Comment: It's going to be hard to judge the error you see without seeing an image.

Comment: I just try the anti aliasing filter but the result is not great. I will upload 3 pic in my post.

Comment: The filter is indeed not great. Have you tried simply using a darker red?

Comment: No, we wish to use this red especially because it is the mark of our app. But how a darker red could save my problem? Oooh the anti aliasing filter ! The filter creates interpolation so if the line is darker... I get it. But Google succeed in doing nice png. I will try a little darker stroke and i update

Comment: "Color only works on RGB layers" omg, gimp :( I stop here for today :( 

Many many thanks for getting me that far, I learn stuff today :) have my upvotes

Comment: Sry cannot validate it as correct answer now that I have log in my account :(